# Output of awk changes when it is echoed

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to find the process id of a process on my computer named "image". I can find this by piping `ps -ef` to `grep image`, which gives me

```
ubuntu    3312  2182  0 11:46 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto image
```

which is what I expect. I then want to get the process id, 2182, which is the third column. I do this by piping that output to `awk '{print $3}'`. This gives the correct output, 2182. However, when I then pass it into echo, like this, `echo $(ps -ef | grep image | awk '{print $3}')`, I get the wrong output, 3312.

What is causing this to happen?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 2182 is the PID of the shell that spawned the `grep` process and 3312 is the PID of the `grep` process, neither of them is the PID of the `image` process. `man pgrep`.

Comment: @EdMorton I was just going to say that. If you are actually grepping for a different process then you need to add a `grep -v grep` into your pipe to kill the `ps` record for the `grep` you are performing. Otherwise your `echo` will only echo the last line of the grep'd `ps` which will be the be the process of the tty you are performing the command from. Something like: `echo $( ps -ef | grep <searchterm> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}')` would do the trick.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it was. The process I was looking for wasn't named image, it was named `./build/camera`, and so wasn't found by grepping for image. I was looking at the process id of `grep`, not of the program I was looking for.

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk. `awk '/<searchterm>/ && !/awk/{print $3}'` is equivalent to `grep <searchterm> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}'`. But as I said - `man pgrep`.